# Dynamic class loading in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, classnotfoundexception, spi, dynamic-class-loaders

I have a whole bunch of framework modules that work fine on OSGi, all the services and components are finding one another and running just fine.

There is however one framework that does some dynamic stuff regarding classes. Basically at some point you give it a class name and it performs Class.forName() and then reflection magic happens.

This works great when running in a standard jvm and using SPI to wire together the frameworks but it fails in OSGi because of course that random class "test.MyTest" that you are trying to approach via the framework is not visible to said framework.

It will throw a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.MyTest not found by framework"

So my question: how can I solve this lack of visibility for the framework that needs to see all? `Import-Package: *`?

**UPDATE**

Assuming OSGi hasn't changed much since 2010 on this front, the article http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html is **very** interesting. I have currently added support for both actively registering classes and a domain factory to be injected via OSGi.

Apart from that the default resolving uses context classloader anyway so if all else fails that will be used to try and load the class.

**UPDATE**

I have added support for the suggested `DynamicImport-Package` as well which is easier for small projects.

Comment: Which framework are you talking about? Do you have any control over the code?

Comment: Yes, it's my own framework

Comment: Then by all means avoid Class.forName(). See my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DynamicImport-Package:*](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package). This will allow the bundle to see all classes. The problem is that you have no real control over what exactly is exposed. So this is normally a last resort and not the recommended way.

You should first try to use Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader() and set it to the classloader of the class you provide to the framework. Sometimes the frameworks also consult this classloader.

The even better way is to find a method in the framework that allows to provide the user classloader.

If you have control over the code then avoid Class.forName(). Instead let the user either give you a class object instead of a class name or let the user give you the combination of a class name and the classloader to use. Both ways work perfectly in and outside OSGi.

Comment: Unfortunately the framework is actually an implementation of a higher level framework and **must** use a string id to identify the class.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get the DynamicImport-Package to work. Anything special I need to do or just set it in the manifest?

Comment: You just set it in the manifest of your framework. You still have to make sure though the package you want to access is exported.

Comment: Heh, it works now but not in combination with the thread context classloader (at least in my test).

Comment: the thread context classloader only works if the framework also uses it. So in your case it would not help.